# Select all checkboxes in gridview from button client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, client-side, checkbox

I have a gridview with rows containing a checkbox. Below the gridview I have a button. When I click it I want to select all the checkboxes from client side. So far I've read about OnClientClick, javascript and so on.. but my code doesn't work. Can someone help me out please?

note: I don't wanna select the checkboxes selecting the checkbox in the header (I found a lot of examples about this), but clicking a button outside the gridview

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server"  ID="MyGridView" EnableViewState="true" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    ><AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

    <Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" SortExpression="Select" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CkBoxSelectET" runat="server" /></EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CkBoxSelectIT" runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Visible="false" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' Visible="false" /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSelect" Text="Select all" BackColor="LightGray" OnClientClick="SelectAll(id);" />

<script type="text/javascript">

var gridViewControl = document.getElementById('<%= MyGridView.ClientID %>');

function SelectAll(id) {
    for (i = 0; i < gridViewControl.elements.length; i++) {
        if (gridViewControl.elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
            gridViewControl.elements[i].checked = document.getElementById(id).checked;
        }
    }
}
```

in c#, when i bind the data:

```
 btnSelect.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "javascript:SelectAll('" + btnSelect.ClientID + "')");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, and it works. I modified slightly the solution of @Ann L.

```
function SelectAll() {

    var frm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];

    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].length; i++) {
        if (document.forms[0].elements[i].id.indexOf('CkBoxSelectIT') != -1) {

                document.forms[0].elements[i].checked = true

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be saying "If my button is 'checked' (that being the element corresponding to the ID you're passing in) then check this checkbox".  Since a button can't be checked, that's not going to work.

You're also saying "On clicking this button, call this Javascript and pass in the value of the variable `id`."  But `id` isn't defined in that context.

If all you want is to select all checkboxes, and don't want to toggle between all/none checked,  this code should work:

HTML:

```
<button id="btnSelect" type="button" onclick="SelectAll" >Select All</button>
```

In javascript:

```
var gridViewControl = document.getElementById('<%= MyGridView.ClientID %>');

function SelectAll() {
    for (i = 0; i < gridViewControl.elements.length; i++) {
        if (gridViewControl.elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
            gridViewControl.elements[i].checked = true;
        }
   }
```

}

You shouldn't need c# code at all.

Comment: I think the actual javascript is more an idea/example, than the actual working code. Variable "gridViewControl" has not been set. You need to make sure to select a correct DOM element into "gridViewControl" variable and then loop through the checkboxes within it. Perfect job for jQuery.

Comment: it loads again the page without doing anything

Comment: Oh, I see.  I didn't notice this at first.  Because you are using an ASP.NET button control, you are automatically doing a postback.  But you don't need to: you're doing this all on the client.  So all you need is an HTML button tag.  I will amend my answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest doing this completely client side using jQuery. I'm assuming new ASP.NET would render IDs for elements the way you named them, so I will use those. (I think there is a setting in ASP.NET to render IDs this way)

Here some sample code that you can put on the bottom of your HTML code, after including jQuery:

```
<script>
    $("#btnSelect").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#MyGridView").find("[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
    });
</script>
```

This will select and check only the checkboxes within the GridView, assuming the rendered ID for the GridView container element is "MyGridView".

Comment: Should I write something in the tag btnSelect? for example onClientClick

Comment: You don't need anything. This basically does the same thing, without involving ASP.NET and it's pretty standard jQuery thing to do. Otherwise you would need to define a javascript function and put its name in "onClientClick". Something like:

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your page? Did you make sure the IDs match what's actually being rendered by ASP.NET. Do some basic troubleshooting ;) I think there is enough here to help you figure out how to do this, other than actually writing your code.

Comment: IDs are correct and I added this jquery: <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"> your code... </script>

Comment: My code has to go within it's own set of <script> tags, outside of the tag where you include jQuery, not within it. My code has to go to the bottom of the page, or at least after the gridView and the button you are trying to script.

Comment: done, now I have two script, one with your code, at the bottom of the page, after gridview and button. But still inside content. But it does not work, it's driving me crazy!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this,Find input elements inside grid by using `getElementsByTagName("input")` . Then iterating and setting the value to checked.

**HTML**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" onclick="selectAll(this)" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function selectAll(chkAll) {
            var gvrecipe = document.getElementById('<%=gvrecipe.ClientID %>');
            var inputs = gvrecipe.getElementsByTagName("input");
            alert(inputs.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if (inputs[i].id.indexOf("_chkSelect") != -1)
                    inputs[i].checked = chkAll.checked;
            }
        }
```